# Is there any difference between reference and lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

By reference, I mean the normal reference- the one which is used in "call by reference" functions. Is there a difference between this reference and lvalue reference?

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of references in C++: lvalue references and rvalue references. Both are references. A function argument that binds to either kind of reference is "passed by reference".

Lvalue references bind to lvalues, and const-lvalue references also bind to rvalues.*

Rvalue references *only* bind to rvalues and never to lvalues.

The utility of separating the two kinds of references lies in the fact that rvalue references can make the assumption that the referred-to value is not aliased (since it is either a pure rvalue (i.e. a temporary) or an xvalue deliberately declared to be eXpiring) and can thus be modified without anyone noticing.

This allows the concept of *moving* resources and *transferring* ownership, which could not be expressed properly in the type system before C++11, when rvalue references were introduced. Before then, there was only one kind of reference, the lvalue reference.

---

<sup>*) The Microsoft compiler also allows binding non-const lvalues references to rvalues. This is non-standard, suprising and confusing.</sup>

---

As a reminder, the taxonomy of value categories in C++ is this:

```
                value
               /     \
         glvalue      rvalue
         /     \      /    \
   lvalue       xvalue      prvalue

   T & f()      T && f()    T f()
```

Underneath is an example: The value category of the function call expression `f()` is as indicated provided that `f` has the respective declared return type (and `T` is not a reference type). Moreover, the return type of the function can be recovered as `decltype(f())`.

Comment: Since the OP added the [visual-c++] tag, you might want to add that there's a language extension that can bind class-type rvalues to non-const lvalue references.

Comment: The confusing part begins when trying to test that with an `int`, because it won't work. It needs an object, e.g. an instance of a class: http://rextester.com/live/CCH78695

Comment: @dyp: Life seems to be too short to invest in becoming an expert at MSVC :-(